# How to implement on-behalf-of flow in Azure function? Fails with 'AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token'

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

From an Azure Function (FuncA), I want to call another Azure Function (FuncB) in a different function app on behalf of the current user.

I'm using AAD as the authentication provider in both apps. FuncA's app and FuncB's app are using separate App Registrations, and I've added FuncB as a 'Required Permisson' in FuncA's App registration.

I'm attempting to get a bearer token that I can pass to Func B but AcquireTokenAsync fails with 'AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token'

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var oldAuthToken = req.Headers.SingleOrDefault(_ => _.Key == "X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN").Value?.FirstOrDefault();

var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(oldAuthToken, 
          "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", 
          userName);

var clientId = "<application id of FuncA's App>";
var clientKey = "<Key of FuncA's App>";
var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientKey);

string tenantId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;

var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/";
var apiIdentifier = "<Func B's application id>";
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiIdentifier, credential, userAssertion);
```

Edit: It works if I use client credential flow (i.e. don't pass userAssertion on the last line of code), but I actually don't want that flow to succeed - I want to control access using the user principal.

Comment: Have you Grant Permission when you added FuncB into FuncA's App registration?

Comment: Hi Joey, Yes - the first time I ran it, it failed with an error asking me to grant permissions. Once I did that it failed with the error above.